# How to create custom less file? magento 2

Tags: magento2, less

I'm having a problem creating my own less file in my Magento 2? there's a tutorial by Alan Storm through the way he creates a custom less file is by using a module, is there a way to do it without using a module? I'm creating a breakpoint less file.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide what you have tries with file path and commands you followed.

Answer (score 5):

Just add new file named `breakpoint.less` at below path:

```
app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<Themename>\web\css\source\
```

and import this file in `_sources.less` file given path below:

```
app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<Themename>\web\css\source\
```

import your file

(if there is not available `_sources.less` file in your theme then go to `vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\source` folder and copy file in your custom theme)

```
@import 'breakpoint.less';
```

1. clear cache
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: nothing happen my friend it compile and deploy but the less file is not loading :(

Answer (score 2):

- Create your less file in the same location that you would normally create the CSS file, just be sure to use the extension .less
- Location of the file should be {module_root_dir}/view/{base|adminhtml|frontend}/path/to/file.less
- Clear your pub/static dir or at least clear the directory in pub/static
- Reference your file in your layout xml file like so

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <head>
          <css src="Vendorname_Modulename::path/to/file.less"/>
      </head>
  </page>
  ```
- Clear your cache
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

If your css file is still not showing its effect on your page, check the page source and see if it's even being attempted to be included.

Comment: thank you for your instruction i'm having an error when compiling here is the error.

Comment: **variable @media-common is undefined in file** my less is located on **app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/breakpoint.less**.

Comment: Remove frontend folder given path 'pub\static\frontend' and cache,
**Clear your cache** and
**bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Comment: @DipeshRangani isn't that exactly what I stated in my answer?