# remove slider and show gallary image as thumbnails in the detail page magento 2

Tags: magento2, gallery

**Remove** the **slider** and **show gallery image** as **thumbnails** on the detail page **Magento 2**.

please anyone can help me how can I solve this??

Comment: Hey @jigar,
Did you found anything ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the template using layout XML, then make any customizations you want within that file:

In `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Module]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`, add the following within the `<body>` tag:

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">path/to/your/template.phtml</argument>
            </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

In this case, you will create a file in `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Module]/Magento_Catalog/templates/path/to/your/template.phtml`.  If you want to start with the native-magento template, you can copy the contents of `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml` into your new template-file.  This would give your a good starting point, but either way, you should be able create the desired output.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer but I am new in Magento 2 so can you guide me how can I make like this.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3334108/87ae898d92482c222955a03215b9ad7d

Comment: [This article will help you create a theme](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html).  For this case, the only required parts are the `registration.php` and `theme.xml`.  Once you have a theme, you should be able to follow the instructions in my answer.

Comment: I have created a custom theme and I have overridden gallery.phtml but I need the design like this. i have a copy this file and put it on that on my theme.

Comment: There are probably a dozen different ways that you could get your gallery to look that way.  [Add a custom css/less file to your theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130303/how-to-create-custom-less-file-magento-2), and start experimenting..

Comment: Also, if you are basing your design on an existing one, go to the site from your screenshot, right click the gallery and click inspect.  That should give you an idea of the css that is used and how you can recreate it.

Comment: that's PSD and I need to show more view image like that.